# How to POST the json payload data inside a telegram chat using the bot API?

Tags: post, telegram

I only get the text "1111" mentioned in the url as the output inside telegram chat and not the json data written inside the code.

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot5168xxxxx8:AAxxxxxxo/sendMessage? chat_id=@alerttest&text=1111"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

data = """
    {
     "stocks": "SEPOWER,ASTEC,EDUCOMP,KSERASERA,IOLCP,GUJAPOLLO,EMCO"
     }
      """"
      
     resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

     print(resp.status_code)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confused about the working of **[HTTP methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)** and **[Telegram API methods](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods)**.

First step: Telegram [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) works with **POST** HTTP method.

It requires the **text** parameter, *passed as GET parameter*: otherwise you'll send an empty message.

This means, that if you're willing to **include the JSON payload** as ***text message*** you have to include your JSON attribute's values into the **Telegram sendMessage text parameter**, otherwise you won't be able to see that into the final message.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following issues with the given code:

1. `url` contains a space.
2. `chat_id` value should be numeric. Use https://web.telegram.org/ to get the chat_id from the URL. It should be a negative number. If it's a channel or supergroup, you should prepend `100` after the minus sign.
3. `&text=1111` should be removed from the URL, as `text` is specified in the body when using the `requests.post()` method.
4. `data` should be a dictionary containing key name `text`.
5. You can not specify `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in headers unless your `data` dictionary has been transcoded to json. This can be solved in the requests.post() call by either changing `data=` to `json=`, or by not specifying `headers` at all.

Working:

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot5168xxxxx8:AAxxxxxxo/sendMessage?chat_id=-739xxxxxx"
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
data = { 'text': 'stocks: SEPOWER,ASTEC,EDUCOMP,KSERASERA,IOLCP,GUJAPOLLO,EMCO' }
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
print(resp.status_code)
```

Working:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot5168xxxxx8:AAxxxxxxo/sendMessage?chat_id=-739xxxxxx"
data = { 'text': 'stocks: SEPOWER,ASTEC,EDUCOMP,KSERASERA,IOLCP,GUJAPOLLO,EMCO' }
resp = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(resp.status_code)
```